# How to implement cross entropy along a dimension?

Tags: pytorch

How can I implement this pseudocode in torch whereby I get cross entropy loss along rows and columns? Torch does not have a dim/axis parameter.

```
import torch

# gen data
logits = torch.rand(16, 16)
labels = np.arange(16)

# pseudo code
l_r = F.cross_entropy(logits, labels, axis=0)  # how to implement?
l_c = F.cross_entropy(logits, labels, axis=1)
```

Comment: There's no axis argument because the assumption is that the label is a collection spanning all available input samples. Applying a loss function on a row would be applying the loss function on a input sample, and not the prediction label with respect to the ground truth. If your labels are actually along a single row, you'll need to process your data to fit the characteristic that the input shape = (C) or (C, N), where C is the number of classes, and N is the batch size. The loss function also must take two inputs that have the same dimensionality.